# Rails 4 - Setting a unique reference between 2 models with the key on the wrong table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a story class and a page class

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :story
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy

    has_one :start, class_name: "Page", foreign_key: "start_id"
end
```

Every story has many pages, and I want to set one as the "start page". The problem is that the way that is coded now, it appears to be looking for the foreign key in the Pages table, instead of the Stories table, becuase when I execute

```
<%= link_to 'Start story', [@story, @story.start] %>
```

I get the following error

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: pages.start_id: SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."start_id" = ? LIMIT 1

Where did I go wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is my `routes.rb`

```
resources :stories do
    resources :pages
end
```

And this is the migration

```
class CreateStories < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :stories do |t|
            t.string :title
            t.text :description

            t.references :start, index: true, foreign_key: true

            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide your routes?

Comment: In which table did you define `start_id` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your own question.  If your story has a 'start' page then stick the foreign key on the stories table

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :start_page, class_name: "Page"
end
```

Table stories, needs a foreign key of start_page_id that references pages(id).  Nothing in the pages table needs to be changed

Comment: but `starting_page` please :)

Comment: I see. I figure that I used `has_one` because it sounds better to say "the story **has one** start page", than saying "the story **belong to** a start page".

Comment: http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

By definition the foreign key resides in the table having `belongs_to` relationship. In your case this is `pages`. That's why you have to change your migration and move `start_id` in `pages`. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) where is the foreign_key.